# Windows 2008 CA Certificate Services

Tags: windows

I have a Windows 2008 server that is not joined to a domain or acting as a domain controller.
However when I request a certificate via the web browser (http:///certsrv and then try to issue it I get an error :

```
The request subject is invalid or too long / Error Constructing or Publishing Certificate.
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you provide the subject (with some characters replaced for obfuscation)?  As the question exists now, there may not be enough information.

Comment: Request attributes are :
country : UK
state : TEST
locality : ABCXYZ
org : ABC
orgunit : ABC123
email : r@1
commonname : test.domain.com

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that running the following resolved the issue but im not sure exactly what this does ??

certutil -setreg ca\CRLFlags +CRLF_ALLOW_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SUBJECT